# PHP - variables don't change value when they should

Tags: php, variables

I'm having and issue with 2 of my variables in my code. I have an if statement that rests inside a for loop. When the if statement executes in the for loop, my two variables should change accordingly, but they don't. I have no functions in my code, so all the variables are in the global scope.

Here is my code:

```
$file = file("../../manpages/structure.txt");
$topicindex = 0;
$topiclineindex = 0;
for($x = 0; count($file) > $x; $x++){
    $data = explode(",",$file[$x]);
    $structure[$topicindex][$topiclineindex] = $file[$x];
    echo '[' . $topicindex . ',' . $topiclineindex . ']';
    $topiclineindex += 1;
    if ($data[0] == "ENDTOPIC") {
        echo "NEXT TOPIC";
        $topicindex += 1;
        $topiclineindex = 0;
    }
}
print_r($structure);
```

This is the output in the browser:

`[0,0][0,1][0,2][0,3][0,4][0,5][0,6][0,7]NEXT TOPICArray ( [0] => Array ( [0] => TOPIC,Topic 1 [1] => SUBTOPIC,Sub Topic 1,intro.txt [2] => SUBTOPIC,Sub Topic 2,intro.txt [3] => ENDTOPIC [4] => TOPIC,Topic 2 [5] => SUBTOPIC,Sub Topic 21,intro.txt [6] => SUBTOPIC,Sub Topic 22,intro.txt [7] => ENDTOPIC ) )`

And this is the contents of structure.txt

```
TOPIC,Topic 1
SUBTOPIC,Sub Topic 1,intro.txt
SUBTOPIC,Sub Topic 2,intro.txt
ENDTOPIC
TOPIC,Topic 2
SUBTOPIC,Sub Topic 21,intro.txt
SUBTOPIC,Sub Topic 22,intro.txt
ENDTOPIC
```

Any and all suggestions are very much appreciated.

EDIT: I've been testing some more, and it seems the newly assigned values don't escape the if statement. On the next iteration of the for loop, `$topicindex` and `$topiclineindex` returned to their previous values of the previous iteration before the if statement was excecuted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IF statement is executed only for the last line because the first ENDTOPIC is actually "ENDTOPIC\n".
See http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php for details about the new line flag

Comment: You are right. I forgot about the newline character. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if ($data[0] == "ENDTOPIC") {
```

with

```
if (trim($data[0]) == "ENDTOPIC") {
```

This will do the trick.
Your IF statement is executed only for the last line because the first ENDTOPIC is actually "ENDTOPIC\n"

trim() function strips "\n"